# Can't add module in Heroku, Django "Error: No module named South"

Tags: django, heroku, django-south

I started using heroku and thought I installed a module the right way:

```
1. source bin/activate
2. pip install south
```

In my requirements.txt I have:

```
Django==1.3
South==0.7.3
psycopg2==2.3.2
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

I also ran:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Which says that all the requirements are satisfied

So it seems that South should be intalled correctly. However, when I run syncdb, I get the error "Error: No module named South"?

Would appreciate any help! Also seems that there are not many tutorials for actually working with Heroku and Django, would be great if you could point me to one.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What is app name in INSTALLED_APPS? It should be 'south' (lowercase).

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to commit your `requirements.txt`. I think Heroku installs only the dependencies from the committed `requirements.txt` and completely disregards any packages you may have installed locally.